# Store an uploaded file temporarilly when there are form errors

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a form with a `FileField` and other fields:

```
from flask_wtf.file import FileField

class FooForm(Form):
    file = FileField()
    #...
```

How I can "persist" file uploads through multiple request? For example, I attach a file to file upload field and write some text to another field. After I click submit, the text doesn't validate, so I display the form again to review the data, but the file is gone now. How can I improve the form so that the user doesn't have to upload the file again?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to store the file on first load and then reference it by ID after that:

```
class FooForm(Form):
    file = FileField()
    file_id = HiddenField()
```

Then in your handler:

```
if form.file_id.data:
    # remove any validators from form.file
    form.file.validators = []

if form.validate():
    possible_file_stream = request.files.get(form.file.name)
    file_data = get_file(possible_file_stream, form.file_id.data)
    # Do things with file data
    return redirect('/somewhere/else')
elif form.file.data:
    file_data = request.files[form.file.name]
    form.file_id.data = save_file(file_data)

# Optionally, if the form should not display the file input
# once one has been uploaded
# del form.file
return render_template("form.html", form=form)
```